# How to override menu link href to be something like javascript:jQuery....?

Tags: 7, navigation

I need to override one menu link in footer to be href like this javascript:jQuery - after click the modal window will open.

Drupal not allowed me to insert it directly to the menu link form.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use [menu_attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) and set an id or class on the menu item. Then in your theme or custom module include a javascript that binds to the id or class.

Comment: Yes this is good opion I have it in my mind, but I was wondering for something without module. Does exist any hook alter function or anything I can do it by?

Comment: Using javascript in the `href` is a bit 'outdated' and discouraged (no reference, sorry). I have not seen any module or function to achieve it in Drupal.

Comment: Its not for me but for the company they decided :D

Comment: I understand dude.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make this happen with the assistance of a module called [Special menu items](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items). Essentially, the module allows you to fill in placeholder / separator menu items to work around the menu item system (the module overrides `theme_link()` when you give it a special path). Per the project page:

> If you use module than require to output a link, go in
>   **/admin/config/system/special_menu_items** and use `<a>` as the HTML tag.
>   You can even use `<a href="#">` if you need to.

In your instance, you could use `<a href="javascript:alert('Hello World!');">` in the configuration page, then add your menu item with the `<nolink>` path to have produce a menu item with the javascript embedded `href`.